# Direct call for card nonce

Tags: square-connect

It would be much easier I think for us to be able to make a simple ajax call to obtain the nonce and/or error return so that we can deal with validation ourselves.  It seems most developers these days like to use their own form validation libraries like jquery validate and the like and it is really difficult to integrate your js library.

to make a question, is it possible to do this and if so, what are the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** possible to do this while adhering to Square's Terms of Service. This implementation was chosen to prevent you from having ever touch a credit card number, etc. and thus having to adhere to the strict rules that come along with that sort of thing.

Comment: The provided implementation makes it seemingly impossible to have more fields (ie name, email etc.) AND unified validation. It does look like Stripe allows for this though, maybe I should just use that.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by unified validation? I encourage you to pick the right product for you and your business, but make sure that you understand the compliance that goes with each decision. If you choose an implementation that is giving your code access to raw PANs, you could be very liable for any damage caused by fraud.

Comment: Rather than "unified" i should have said "consistent".  I use a library for form validation (jquery.validate) and your library seems to couple the requestForNonce to your own validation methods, this makes adding fields that require validation a mystery.   What do you mean by PAN?  If i don't post the cc#s but rather only results from your nonce request, doesn't that clear my liability? 

I guess I don't understand how it is any different for me to post to your  servers and do a simple request for nonce and retrieve a nonce object

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Why can't you have additional fields that you validate with your library and then submit to your backend along with the retrieved nonce? PAN is a credit card number. Our implementation uses Iframes to host the input fields, so a credit card never hits your servers. If you were submitting a request directly, it would be.

Comment: I did try that - I made a rule with my validation library  that checked for an empty nonce field and if empty run your requestCardNonce function but for some reason after running that, form.submit would error as "undefined" my guess it that your library re-assigns the form object.  Since your library is a bit optimized it proved too tedious to deduce.  It also seemed to elude me how to return a simple value from the requestCardNonce function to providing feedback to my validation was equally frustrating.

Comment: I still don't see how sending square a request for nonce with simple post exposes the credit card any differently if i do it with javascript straight from the form.  Isn't that what happens buried in your library thats embedded anyways?   - I do appreciate your taking time with me.

Comment: I am happy to help. In your desired model, your client javascript would have to have access to the credit card number. That means an attacker would only have to figure out how to get some malicious javascript running on your site to cause some problems. This is a very real issue, that you can read more about here: https://gwillem.gitlab.io/2016/10/11/5900-online-stores-found-skimming/. If you share your code, I might be able to help you find an appropriate validation solution.

Comment: Understandably this is how those chose implementation. Which brings up other issues such as cross-origin frames, in my case. If the website owner / developer aren't aware of security risks, well they shouldn't be in this business. PCI - DSS and SSL certificates are put in place for this such things and people should be held liable for their unintelligent decisions. Instead of coddling individuals, why not let them reap the consequences. I for one find this to be very locked down like Apple. Having worked with various other processing libraries, this is really absurd.